# Cannot delete files from firebase collection

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-tools

I am following the example listed [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/delete-collections), except with modifications due to the [API](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/blob/master/src/firestore/delete.js#L22) of the new `firebase-tools`.

```
exports.clearMessages = functions.runWith({ timeoutSeconds: 540, memory: '2GB' }).https.onCall(messagesController.clearMessages)

export const clearMessages = async (data, context) => {
    const uid = context.auth.uid
    const path = `users/${uid}/messages`
    return firebase_tools.firestore.delete('flightApp3', path, {
        recursive: true,
        shallow: true,
        allCollections: true
    }).then(result => {
        console.log('delete result', result)
        return result
    })
}
```

However, when I run this , I see the following displayed in Cloud Functions log:

```
Unhandled error { Error
    at Error.FirebaseError (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/error.js:9:18)
    at module.exports (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/getProjectId.js:10:19)
    at Command.module.exports (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/requirePermissions.js:11:21)
    at /user_code/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/command.js:154:38
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:135:7)
  name: 'FirebaseError',
  message: 'No project active. Run with \u001b[1m--project <projectId>\u001b[22m or define an alias by\nrunning \u001b[1mfirebase use --add\u001b[22m',
  children: [],
  status: 500,
  exit: 1,
  stack: 'Error\n    at Error.FirebaseError (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/error.js:9:18)\n    at module.exports (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/getProjectId.js:10:19)\n    at Command.module.exports (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/requirePermissions.js:11:21)\n    at /user_code/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/command.js:154:38\n    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:135:7)',
  original: undefined,
  context: undefined }
```

However, I'm pretty sure I have an active project in my firebase CLI.

```
$ firebase use
Active Project: production (flightApp3)

Project aliases for /Users/myUser/Developer/flightApp3/cloud:

* default (flightApp3)
* production (flightApp3)

Run firebase use --add to define a new project alias.
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a complete example.  How are you calling `clearMessages`?  What is `FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID`?

Comment: @DougStevenson editted

Comment: I don't think your local project carries over to the Cloud Functions environment, but am not sure how to pass in a project ID on the calls there. I'll ask around.

Answer (score 2):

some options cannot be mixed ...

```
return firebase_tools.firestore.delete('flightApp3', path, {
    // allCollections: true,
    recursive: true,
    yes: true
}).then(() => {
    return {
      path: path 
    };
});
```

that's how the path is being built up (`path` and `allCollections` also do not seem to make sense together): `projects/${project}/databases/(default)/documents/users/${uid}/messages`

[getProjectId.js](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/blob/master/src/getProjectId.js) checks for `rc.projects` (where `options.project` is option `--project`):

```
module.exports = function(options, allowNull) {
    if (!options.project && !allowNull) {
        var aliases = _.get(options, "rc.projects", {});
        ...
```

these `rc.projects` are the `projects` from the `.firebaserc` file:

```
{
   "projects": {
        "default": "flightApp3"
    }
}
```

or run `firebase use default` to switch from alias `production` to `default` (or remove alias `production` once for a test). `FirestoreDelete(project, path, options)` also does not care about `options.token` nor `options.project` anymore (as the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/delete-collections) suggests).

---

`$ firebase firestore:delete --help` explains the command-line options:

```
Usage: firestore:delete [options] [path]

Delete data from Cloud Firestore.

Options:

  -r, --recursive    Recursive. Delete all documents and sub-collections. 
                     Any action which would result in the deletion of child
                     documents will fail if this argument is not passed.

                     May not be passed along with --shallow.


  --shallow          Shallow. Delete only parent documents and ignore documents
                     in sub-collections. Any action which would orphan documents
                     will fail if this argument is not passed.

                     May not be passed along with --recursive.


  --all-collections  Delete all. Deletes the entire Firestore database,
                     including all collections and documents.

                     Any other flags or arguments will be ignored.


  -y, --yes          No confirmation. Otherwise, a confirmation prompt will appear.
```

the [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase-tools) (the output above) is at version `6.0.1`.

---

just found a relevant comment (but possibly obsolete):

> The `token` must be set in the functions config, and can be generated at the command line by running `firebase login:ci`.

this hints for [environment configuration](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env), so that `functions.config().fb.token` has the `token`:

```
firebase functions:config:set fb.token="THE TOKEN"
```

one can also obtain the projectId from `process.env.FIREBASE_CONFIG.projectId`.

Comment: The documentation is out of date and doesn't match the API of the recent `firebase-tools`

Answer (score 0):

Docs https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/delete-collections

In `/functions` directory install `firebase-tools`

```
    "firebase-tools": "^7.16.2"
```

In cloud function import `firebase-tools` and call `delete`

```js
const firebaseTools = require("firebase-tools");
...
firebaseTools.firestore.delete(workspaceRef.path, {
                project: process.env.GCLOUD_PROJECT, // required
                recursive: true, // required
                yes: true // required
              })
```

There is no need for a token when calling `firebase-tools` from a cloud function.

Also the link to the API https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/blob/v7.16.2/src/firestore/delete.js with code implementation for `FirestoreDelete` seems wrong.

I'm successfully calling `.delete(path, options)` but the code says `.delete(project, path, options)`?